# Why doesn't Barney wear the Duckie Tie?

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

In [*How I Met Your Mother*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460649/) Barney loses the Duckie Tie bet in October 2011 when he cannot perform the Benihana routine satisfactorily. He was to wear it for 1 year, hence October 2012. However, I was catching reruns of the episodes and saw the *Broath* episode, where he was not wearing it, though it would have been well inside the duckie tie year. There are two possible causes: *Broath* was one of Ted's memories outside the duckie tie year, and just broadcast here *OR* the bet was invalidated some time later. Anyone know?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's an episode earlier in that season (before the "Broath" episode) where Barney is going to have dinner with Nora's parents, but he doesn't want to wear the tie.  He exchanges 3 slaps to get rid of the tie.  The episode is called "Disaster Averted".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaster_Averted

Comment: And he never goes inside for the dinner, right? Bad exchange.

Comment: Well, the dinner was in a later episode.  Don't wanna give too many spoilers, but he did go to the dinner.

Comment: I edited to make it a little clearer that the answer refers to an episode prior to The Broath.

Comment: Good call.  I was in the middle of doing that myself. :D  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real late answer, but the broath is about Quinn, which is the season after Nora. In Disaster Averted they make a deal about the Ducky Tie where he trades more slaps to take it off before meeting Nora’s parents.